# Error using jlink with automatic module in Maven project

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, jlink

I'm trying to use jlink to create a custom JRE for my Maven project using the following command:

```
mvn clean javafx:jlink
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: automatic module cannot be used with jlink: org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore from file:///C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.13/httpcore-4.4.13.jar
```

I have already tried adding the following to my pom.xml file, but it didn't help:

```
<configuration>
    <automaticModuleName>true</automaticModuleName>
</configuration>
```

My pom file looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Project</name>
    <description>project</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-alpha.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okio</groupId>
            <artifactId>okio</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-alpha.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>17</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.project.gui.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-httpcore</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
                                    <version>4.4.13</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                    <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jlinkbase/lib</outputDirectory>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

this is my module-info.java:

```
module project {
    requires transitive java.desktop;
    requires javafx.base;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires transitive javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.swing;
    requires okhttp3;
    requires okio;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;
    requires org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore;
    requires org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient;
    requires java.base;
    requires org.apache.httpcomponents.httpmime;
    requires org.apache.commons.codec;
    requires java.xml;
    requires java.net.http;
    
    opens com.project.gui;
    opens com.project.gui.controllers;
    opens com.project.utils;
    opens com.project.logic;
    opens com.project.pojos;
    opens com.project.pojos.actions;
}
```

How can I resolve this issue and successfully create a custom JRE for my Maven project using jlink?

Comment: You might want to consider using the [java.net.http](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/package-summary.html) package instead of Apache httpcore.